# update the value in datetime field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, datetime

I have jquery `datetimepicker`, and in them value field I set now date :

```
today = new Date();
var aaa = today.format("yyyy-mm-dd' 'HH:MM");
}

$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker()
        .datetimepicker({value:aaa,step:10});
```

There is work fine, but for me need to update this value every minute, how can I do this?

I change the value :

```
    ref()
    function ref(){
            today2 = new Date();
            var bbb = today2.format("yyyy-mm-dd' 'HH:MM");
            aaa = bbb;
            setInterval("ref()",10000);
    }
```

but I don't know how to set the value to `datetimepicker`.

My trying (DOESN'T WORK!)

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker()
        .datetimepicker({value:aaa,step:10});
```

and

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker('setDate', aaa);
```

Comment: i don't know, maybe window.setInterval can help me, but i'm not understand how modificate window.setInterval to change date?
Can you explain please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getNow(){
    return new Date().format("yyyy-mm-dd' 'HH:MM");
}

$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({'defaultDate': getNow()}); 

function repeat(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker('setDate', getNow()); 
        repeat();
    }, 60000);
}
repeat();
```